# Unable to boot system in ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I completed my installation of Ubuntu but my system still directly boots to windows, I checked the boot order and it looks like this:
[image]

Ubuntu is listed under 0000 but that is not even present in the current order.

I looked at existing answers that suggest use of efibootmgr but it did not work. Also I found an answer to set the default system, however I would prefer if I can get a prompt to chose the operating system every time I boot in.

EDIT: I also tried grub customizer and I am getting an error as:

```
grub-mkconfig couldn't be executed successfully. error message:
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow'.
```

Comment: Have you tried boot-repair: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Can you select ubuntu at the UEFI menu? You may need to change UEFI boot options to make it boot the ubuntu entry first. Otherwise the Boot-repair tool suggested above may work. Some notebooks require additional steps. Please edit and add your brand/model.

Comment: @ManishKumarBisht 
the alternative you suggested doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @CelticWarrior the laptop specifications are acer aspire e5 -575 54e8

Comment: How can i check if The OS is correctly installed or not, i think i have some  mistake there.

Comment: Similar Acer notebooks require setting a supervisor password: This is a fairly complete guide that should work for you with the necessary adaptations: http://p-s.co.nz/wordpress/dual-boot-ubuntu-16-04-on-win-10-acer-aspire-e15/